# Python dataframe: simple string split that includes '-'

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, split

Happy New Year guys. I have a Dataframe that contains int and strings in each columns. In my string column, some of my value contains '-' in the middle and I want to delete any string that follows after '-'. Take a look at my df below.

```
input:
    buzz_id     facet   facet_cls   facet_val   p_buzz_date
0   95713207    A3      Small           MN        20160101
1   95713207    S3      Small-box       Tbd       20160101
2   95713207    F1      Medium          es        20160101
3   95713207    A2      Medium-box      esf       20160101
4   95713207    A1      Dum-pal         ess       20160101
...


output:
    buzz_id     facet   facet_cls   facet_val   p_buzz_date
0   95713207    A3      Small           MN        20160101
1   95713207    S3      Small           Tbd       20160101
2   95713207    F1      Medium          es        20160101
3   95713207    A2      Medium          esf       20160101
4   95713207    A1      Dum             ess       20160101
...
```

So in my 'facet_cls' columns, anything that goes after '-' (including '-') need to be deleted. Also my data itself is very big, so I was hoping to use fastest process that I can find. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and then select only first values of lists by `str[0]`:

```
df['facet_cls'] = df['facet_cls'].str.split('-').str[0]
print (df)
    buzz_id facet facet_cls facet_val  p_buzz_date
0  95713207    A3     Small        MN     20160101
1  95713207    S3     Small       Tbd     20160101
2  95713207    F1    Medium        es     20160101
3  95713207    A2    Medium       esf     20160101
4  95713207    A1       Dum       ess     20160101
```

Detail:

```
print (df['facet_cls'].str.split('-'))
0          [Small]
1     [Small, box]
2         [Medium]
3    [Medium, box]
4       [Dum, pal]
Name: facet_cls, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it using lambda expression as follow:

```
df['facet_cls'] = df['facet_cls'].apply(lambda x:x.split('-')[0])
```

Comment: Yes, but apply is not recommended when there are other approaches. Nice 1

Comment: It would be really helpful if you enlighten me why other approaches are recommended over apply.

Comment: I'm going for lunch now, I'll try to find a reference after.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar - it is not recommended, because it failed if some `NaN`s in data. `str.split` and `str[0]` working with `NaN`s nice.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar See this: https://ys-l.github.io/posts/2015/08/28/how-not-to-use-pandas-apply/ and this: https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6. It has to do with apply not being a vectorized and thus loops through all rows/cols.

Comment: @AntonvBR thank you. I will surely look for other options before going to apply in future.

Comment: While on the subject, Sofia Heisler's [PyCon talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HN5d490_KKk) on the subject is a must.